# How much Swap memory should I alocate for 4GB (3.3GB Useable) RAM in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ram, swap

I am thinking of installing `Ubuntu 16.04` in My Laptop (`HP Probook 440 G1`). It has `4GB RAM`. SO my question is How much space should I allocate for `swap area`?

**Note**:

*1*. I read some articles about it but some said *1.5 times* of RAM, some said *2 times* of RAM. I'm really confused here.

*2*. Can actually swap area increase my PC speed? Because I know that hard drive is too slow then RAM.
**Thanks in Advance**.

Comment: Swap is only beneficial for a) hibernating, and/or b) when or if your computer runs out of RAM. The second answer in the thread suggested by @Anwar is by far the most beneficial.

Comment: With only 4G RAM, I'd suggest 1-1.5xRAM=swap. So, 4-6G swap. Swap won't INCREASE your PC speed... it's slow hard disk working as virtual RAM.